# Vocabulary – ice hockey etc – does one ' "score" two assists'?

Tags: verbs

In ice-hockey, we score goals. What verb do we use with assists?

Can we say "*He scored three points in the game: two goals and one assist*" or "*he scored two assists in the game*". If not, what verb do we use?

Comment: What interests me is whether I can use the combination to score 2 assists. According to a few answers I got here and elsewhere, this is what American and Canadian broadcasters do on a daily basis. Now, I can die with a smile on my face. 

Comment: "He scored three points in the game: two goals and one assist"  is misleading. It puts the points on the same level  as the assists and they have two different tabulation systems. So, if you are putting them together, I would not use score for those two direct objects.

Comment: But now I see that it is possible, at least on Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_players_with_eight_or_more_points_in_an_NHL_game  This is a list of players who have scored eight or more points in a National Hockey League game. Scoring eight or more points in a single game is considered a great feat and has happened only 16 times, by 13 players.

Comment: Please refer to my comment under Edwin Ashworth's answer. You score a goal and get or are awarded an assist. Or make an assist. Confirmed by a die-hard Bruins fan So, if I were you, I would believe me. :)  Also, under TInfoil. I called the Boston Globe's Sports Desk....

Answer (score 3):

The context is ice hockey:

1. And one sees: to get an assist or more formally, to be awarded an assist, to be credited with an assist.

[Assist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assist_(ice_hockey)#:%7E:text=Players%20who%20gain%20an%20assist,or%20less%20than%20a%20goal.)

2. USA Hockey

> Up to a maximum of two **assists shall be awarded** to those player(s) who
> had possession of the puck immediately prior to the goal being scored.

[National Hockey League](http://www.nhl.com/ice/page.htm?id=25011)

You score a point when you shoot the puck through the goal posts, and whoever helped you is given or awarded an assist.

- He scored two goals and **got or had** two assists in the game.

**score is only for goals**. Not for assists.

However, you can say: He was awarded two goals and two assists.

(When a goal is scored, there can be up to two players who get assists. Assists are recorded for a player.)

I just heard on TV re the Bruins: He made two goals and four assists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In hockey, an assist is scored as one point in the assisting player’s record. This is from the National Hockey League:

> When a player scores a goal, an “assist” shall be credited to the
> player or players taking part in the play immediately preceding the
> goal, but no more than two assists can be given on any goal. Each
> “assist” shall count one point in the player’s record.
> <sub>Source: [NHL—Rule 57   Goals and
> Assists](http://www.nhl.com/ice/page.htm?id=25011)</sub>

And here are some usage examples:

> McAuliffe led the way with four points, scoring one goal and three
> assists in Harvard’s furious second period strike.
>  <sub>Source:
> [The Crimson—No. 10 Princeton Shocks W.
> Hockey](https://www.thecrimson.com/article/2004/2/4/no-10-princeton-shocks-w-hockey/?page=1) (2004)</sub>

> In his NHL career that spanned 18 years, Carpenter played 1,178 games,
> scoring 320 goals and 408 assists for 728 points.
>  <sub>Source:
> [Wikipedia—Bobby Carpenter (ice
> hockey)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobby_Carpenter_(ice_hockey)) (2006)</sub>

> In 1942, at the age of 21, Richard scored an assist in his first game
> with the Montreal Canadians and then a goal and an assist in his
> second.
>  <sub>Source: [The Pink Puck—This Day in Hockey
> History...](https://thepinkpuck.com/2019/11/07/this-day-in-hockey-history-november-8-1942-and-1952-richard-richer-in-goals/) (2019)</sub>

> Ken Willis is still high scorer, having ten goals and two assists for
> 22 points. . . . A composite score including goals, assists, points,
> and minutes in penalties follows . . . 
> <sub>Source: [Princeton
> Alumni Weekly, Volume
> 35](https://books.google.com/books?id=0hJbAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA373&dq=hockey+scored+two+assists)
> (1935)</sub>

Note that assist scores are not part of the game score, which counts only goals.

Comment: They simply do. See above. Perhaps you are confusing player score with game score. If you were to report: *"Carpenter played 1,178 games, scoring 320 goals and being awarded 408 assists for 728 points"* instead of: *"Carpenter played 1,178 games, scoring 320 goals and 408 assists for 728 points,"* you would be dismissed from your job. In contemporary AmE.

Comment: *Scoring three assists* / *score an assist* . . . do you really not see the same verb? In any case, you and the old timer will have to let the native speakers know they are using their language wrong.

Comment: I just called the Boston Globe's Sport Desk and received confirmation: to score an assist is wrong and the editor would not approve, said the young reporter manning the phones for the desk. So, there it is.  You might want to call them yourself.....as we are home to the Bruins, I would think that is a pretty good usage reference.

Comment: I rather imagine neighbor Harvard is a pretty good usage reference as well.

Comment: Last I checked, the Boston Globe was not a sports publication either.

Comment: The Boston Globe's **sports desk** is a sports publication. Sports are a big deal around here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sports_in_Boston

Answer (score -1):

In soccer, I think the usual verb is '**have**'.

'V an assist' is relatively new. But there are almost 3½ million Google hits for ["had three assists"](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&ei=EVAyYNS1HpeGhbIPsfSQkAo&q=%22had+three+assists%22&oq=%22had+three+assists%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsAM6BggAEAcQHlCjzwJY7YEDYLmFA2gBcAJ4AIABnQyIAdo4kgEJMy4yLjctMy4ymAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiUgvyx-_ruAhUXQ0EAHTE6BKIQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) and over 5 million for ["had two assists"](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&ei=RFAyYLm0FISjgQaT8oKYBA&q=%22had+two+assists%22&oq=%22had+two+assists%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCAgAEAUQChAeOggIABAIEAcQHjoKCAAQBxAFEAoQHlCqug1Yy74NYJDCDWgDcAB4AIABZYgBvAKSAQMzLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwi55prK-_ruAhWEUcAKHRO5AEMQ4dUDCA0&uact=5), many obviously relevant, for instance.

Here are, for comparison, various other verbs which are logical candidates found in raw Google data for "Ved two assists":

- *had two assists* > 5 million
- [*scored two assists*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=_3IyYKWxFaqChbIPurWvmAY&q=%22scored+two+assists%22&oq=%22scored+two+assists%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANQooYVWMSlFWCiqBVoAXAAeACAAccBiAHmBZIBAzguMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjlrOPZnPvuAhUqQUEAHbraC2MQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) 640 000
- [*totaled/totalled two assists*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=zHQyYJi5IMXB8gK58rN4&q=%22totaled+two+assists%22&oq=%22totaled+two+assists%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsANQ6oICWPaPAmDBmwJoAXACeACAAVKIAbcDkgEBNpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiYz9e1nvvuAhXFoFwKHTn5DA8Q4dUDCA0&uact=5) 15 000
- [*made two assists*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=hp&ei=8nIyYNSlCrmajLsPh5yGkA8&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYDKBAtrQ4i2I4kyg-i2lwfbxjkDxs9uW&q=%22achieved+two+assists%22&oq=%22achieved+two+assists%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKsCMgUIIRCrAjIFCCEQqwI6CAgAELEDEIMBOgUILhCxAzoOCC4QsQMQgwEQxwEQowI6CwguELEDEMcBEKMCOggILhCxAxCDAToRCC4QsQMQgwEQxwEQowIQkwI6AggAOgUIABCxAzoECAAQCjoICAAQFhAKEB46BggAEBYQHjoFCAAQhgM6BQghEKABUKgOWL1hYPVkaABwAHgAgAFdiAH-DJIBAjIymAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjU5r7TnPvuAhU5DWMBHQeOAfIQ4dUDCAk&uact=5) 1 000
- [*achieved two assists*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=XXQyYKPtCJGpgAbIlrnwDw&q=%22achieved+two+assists%22&oq=%22achieved+two+assists%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANQzsUCWPjXAmC26QJoAXAAeACAAWuIAZ8EkgEDNi4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjjj8mAnvvuAhWRFMAKHUhLDv4Q4dUDCA0&uact=5) 1 000
- [*amassed two assists*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=jHQyYPC8Fom_gQbE6o2wCw&q=%22amassed+two+assists%22&oq=%22amassed+two+assists%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANQ0dkDWI3vA2DK8QNoAnAAeACAAYcBiAGFBJIBAzUuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjwsouXnvvuAhWJX8AKHUR1A7YQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) 1 000

and the multi-word verb

- [*came up with two assists*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=8XQyYNisHtHygQaXkIWQDQ&q=%22came+up+with+two+assists%22&oq=%22came+up+with+two+assists%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKsCMgUIIRCrAjIFCCEQqwJQwI0DWMCNA2CRmQNoAXAAeACAAUmIAYwBkgEBMpgBAKABAqABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiY6afHnvvuAhVRecAKHRdIAdIQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) 133 000

There will be false positives, of course, and raw Google data is not too reliable, but there's a clear preference, with a clear second and third. Then again, some sentences might work better with a verb other than *have*. This colligation (preferred V-N pairing) example is, as said, new, and just settling down.

....................

Note that your first example

- "*He scored three points in the game, two goals and one assist*"

does not have a compound object (as in "He scored two tries and a conversion") but an enlarging/explaining adjunct. A colon could (and often would) replace the comma. This means that neither 'goals' nor 'assist' has to be an accepted direct object of 'scored'.  "I made friends with two girls in France: one Irish, the other Pakistani." However, in ice hockey, this appears to be an appositive as both goals and assists (up to 2 for the latter) score 'points' for players. Lambie's answer gives this interpretation; it's getting into jargon, but is probably on-topic as many follow ice hockey.

....................

Also note that "He scored two assists" in soccer has a diferent subsense for 'score' than "He scored two goals". If A scored (made) two assists and B scored a goal from each of them, a total of 2 goals only resulted. Two goals were scored (in the normal sense).

Comment: Can we then say "He scored/collected/reached/had 3 points in the game, 2 goals and one assist?" Which verb to choose to cover both goals and assists?

Comment: I'd not use a single verb. But have you checked for "scored two assists"? There are quite a few hits, so the usage is at least becoming idiomatic.

Comment: Yeah, I have just found examples of Wayne Gretzky scoring 8 points in one game. So the verb score probably works fine.

Comment: @JakubMálek Why bother with soccer??

Comment: @Lambie ELU is usage-orientated. [Soccer seems to attract more viewers than ice hockey even in the States](https://worldsoccertalk.com/2020/07/10/why-soccer-is-bigger-than-hockey-in-the-united-states/#:~:text=And%20when%20it%20comes%20to,fifth%2Dfavorite%20at%204%25.). In England, where the language is also spoken ....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Of course, football (soccer) attracts more viewers than ice hockey in the US. That has nothing to do with the lingo. Believe it or not, last night I went to my local supermarket (not far from Boston) where the manager is a huge **Bruins** fan. **He confirmed to me that in ice hockey players score goals and that one simply does not say: a player scored an assist**. He even frowned at the suggestion. Players get x number of assists or have or are given or are awarded them. So, almost straight from the horse's mouth....So, that is very much usage. And I am a big soccer fan.